# Group By with row values as column name and group concat

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am searching for a solution for the SQL problem:

I have input table like this:

| RId | AId | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 76 | 734 | TKI |
| 76 | 528 | NPlat |
| 76 | 735 | TKI |
| 77 | 713 | Plat |
| 77 | 749 | IO |
| 77 | 739 | TKI |
| 77 | 714 | NPlat |
| 78 | 518 | Plat |
| 73 | 519 | Plat |
| 73 | 518 | Plat |

And I want this kind of output:

| RId | TKI | IO | NPlat | Plat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 73 |  |  |  | 518, 519 |
| 76 | 734, 735 |  | 528 |  |
| 77 | 739 | 749 | 714 | 713 |
| 78 |  |  |  | 518 |

I tried with `PIVOT`, but it's not working. Also tried with the `GROUP BY` and `PARTITION BY` together, but no success.

Can anybody have any idea to solve this?

Note: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3).

Edited:
My attempts:

```
select 
RId,
case when Type = 'TKI' then STRING_AGG(AId, ' ') END AS TKI,
case when Type = 'IO' then STRING_AGG(AId, ' ') END AS IO,
case when Type = 'NPlat' then STRING_AGG(AId, ' ') END AS NPlat,
case when Type = 'Plat' then STRING_AGG(AId, ' ') END AS Plat
from tbl_A
group by RId, Type;
```

STRING_AGG is not a generic function in SQL server 2016.

```
select 
RId,
[TKI] = COUNT(*) over(partition by Type),
[IO] = COUNT(*) over(partition by Type),
[NPlat] = COUNT(*) over(partition by Type),
[Plat] = COUNT(*) over(partition by Type)
from tbl_A
group by RId, Type
order by RId;
```

Comment: please share your attempt query

Comment: @DaleK, As I said in my post I have tried to get desired output with a group-by and partition-by query but it didn't work. and I think it is not compulsory to put my query here? because what am I trying it didn't solve that's why I am here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the `Aid` into `csv` format first and then perform the pivot

```
select *
from   (
           select  Rid, [Type], 
                   Aid = stuff(
                             (select ',' + convert(varchar(10), x.Aid)
                             from   tbl x 
                             where  x.Rid = t.Rid
                             and    x.[Type] = t.[Type]
                             order by x.Aid
                             for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
           from    tbl t
           group by Rid, [Type]
       ) d
       pivot
       (
            max(Aid)
            for [Type] in ([TKI], [IO], [NPlat], [Plat])
       ) p
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3a4c8bc0c0765a119330da2f07382dd9)

Comment: Aggregating and pivoting is an excellent option.

Comment: Cool it worked thanks @Squirrel

Answer (score 1):

Simple Use Stuff with Pivot :

```
SELECT RID,[TKI],[IO],[NPlat],[Plat]
FROM 
(SELECT RID,TYPE,AID = STUFF((
                                SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,AID)
                                FROM test t
                                WHERE t.RID = test.RID AND t.TYPE = test.type                               
                                FOR XML PATH('')
                                ), 1, 1, '')
FROM test 
)sorce
PIVOT 
( 
max(AID) FOR type IN ([TKI],[IO],[NPlat],[Plat]) 
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: This also works, just a little change to get exact output: Adding Order by clause for AID inside STUFF. thanks @Piyush